# php pdo how to pull down and set default values from the database

Tags: php, pdo, html-select

```php
$select_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM new_product WHERE `user_id` = :id');
$select_stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$_GET['id']));
$row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">尺寸</label>
  <select class="form-control"  name ="Size" id="Size">
    <option>30*60</option>
    <option>15*90</option>
    <option>15*17.3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I would like to ask how I can use the foreach to select the value brought out of the database to the default value. For example: my database value is 15 * 90, how to select option =15 * 90 I use PDO here

Comment: What do you mean by default value?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want the select option that corresponds to data from the database to be selected?

Comment: _Small Point_ That dropdown is not going to return you anything useful to the PHP unless the options have a value attribute for example `<option value="1800">30*60</option>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly  The value I brought out from the database is preset to the same select option value

Comment: Start by changing the SELECT to get only the columns you want, makes the select more effficient and tells us what you are getting from the table

Comment: @RiggsFolly Assuming that I have value, how to distinguish select option foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a loop to process all the results from the query and add the relevant parts of each row to the HTML

```
<?php
$select_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT xx,desc FROM new_product WHERE `user_id` = :id');
$select_stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$_GET['id']));

?>  
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">尺寸</label>
    <select class="form-control"  name ="Size" id="Size">
<?php
while ( $row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
    // these are just example column names as you dont tell us 
    // what the columns you want to use are called

    echo "<option value='$row[xx]'>$row[desc]</option>";

endwhile;
?>
    </select>
</div>
```